# DataGridView, BindingSource and sorting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, ado.net, datagridview, bindingsource

I am emulating the functionality of an old app in VB.Net.  I have a DataGridView on my form which is bound to a BindingSource.  I have a button on the toolbar which lanuches a sort dialog.  The sort dialog allows sorting by up to 3 columns.

So I'm building a string from the results of the dialog and setting the BindingSource.Sort property with it.  But this doesn't update my DataGridView.  Am I missing a step - do I need to tell something to refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this with a simple test app, and it sorted without having to call any refresh. Can you post some code? Are you sure you're building up the Sort string correctly?

Comment: Answer is that it works fine - I did something stupid.  Too bad I can't have all of you looking over my shoulder.

Comment: :) Thanks for accepting the answer, although it wasn't much of an answer. I figured it had to be some simple oversight.

Comment: Please post your solution as well. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to call the DataGridView.DataBind() method?

I'm so used to ASP.NET that I forget the WinForms stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What is the underlying object, and does it support sorting?  You can check via the .SupportsSorting property (iirc).  If it is a DataTable then you should be ok.

Have you tried applying the sort directly to the Grid?

You can try calling **BindingSource.ResetBindings(false)** after you update the sort property, just to be safe, but you shouldn't have to.